# Dumb sed/Regex Mistake?

Tags: regex, bash, sed

`sed -i.bak -e 's/^\s+({\s+group.+;\s+port.+;)\s+cp.+/    \1 }/g' <file>`

I'm getting an error:

``` sed: -e expression #1, char 48: invalid reference \1 on ``s' command's RHS ```

I've done these sed commands several times before and haven't had this issue.  Did I stumble onto a nuanced character pattern that I'm missing?  I've tested the regex on a website, so i'm pretty sure that it's fine.  I've looked at numerous sed examples online just for this and can't find anything.  Thanks in advance.
Example line to match:

`{ group = "127.0.0.1";  port = 222; cpu = 33; },`

Comment: Does it work with `'s/^[[:space:]]*\({[[:space:]]*group.*;[[:space:]]*port.*;\)[[:space:]]*cp.*/    \1 }/g'`?

Comment: I don't know if it is the main problem but: capturing parenthesis need to be escaped, `\s` isn't supported, you should use `[ \t]` instead or a posix character class, and the + quantifier isn't supported too.

Comment: That error is because in default BRE mode of `sed` you are using unescaped `(...)` that doesn't make a captured group. You need to use `-E` flag for extended regex mode and then `(...)` will make it a group. Besides `\s` should be replaced by `[ \t]`

Comment: Or try `sed -i.bak -r -e 's/^\s+({\s+group.+;\s+port.+;)\s+cp.+/    \1 }/g' <file>`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the `-r` with `-e` did the trick.  I had tried the `-E` earlier and received a less descriptive error than with `-e`.  Thanks.

Comment: @TriHard8: I added an answer with a bit of explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current expression is parsed as a BRE (Basic Regular Expression). It means:

1) parentheses must be escaped to dentote a capturing  group,
 2) `\s` is not supported, must be replaced with `[ \t]` or `[[:space:]]`
 3) `+` quantifier should be turned into `\{1,\}` since it is not supported

You need to pass `-r` option (in other OSes, `-E` may do this job instead) to make the engine parse it as ERE:

```
sed -i.bak -r -e 's/^\s+({\s+group.+;\s+port.+;)\s+cp.+/ \1 }/g' <file>
```